# How to make a Junit test case fail if there is any exception in the code?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I wrote a Junit test to unit test my code. I want my Junit test case to fail when I get any exception in my code. I tried using an assert statement, but even when I get an exception in my code, my Junit test case is passing. Please can anyone tell me how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you use `fail` ?

Comment: Please show your code. JUnit should fail tests automatically if they throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assert that a global variable "excepted" = null or something like that and initialize it to equal some information string in the catch block.

Answer (score 43):

I strongly recommend that you must test your functionality only. If an exception is thrown, the test will automatically fail. If no exception is thrown, your tests will all turn up green.

But if you still want to write the test code that should fail the in case of exceptions, do something like :-

```
@Test
public void foo(){
   try{
      //execute code that you expect not to throw Exceptions.
   }
   catch(Exception e){
      fail("Should not have thrown any exception");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually your test should fail when an exception in code is thrown. Of course, if you catch this exception and do not throw it (or any other exception) further, test won't know about it. In this case you need to check the result of method execution.
Example test:

```
@Test
public void test(){
  testClass.test();
}
```

Method that will fail the test:

```
public void test(){
  throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Method that will not fail the test

```
public void test(){
  try{
    throw new RuntimeException();
  } catch(Exception e){
    //log
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both the following tests will fail without further coding:

```
@Test
public void fail1() {
    throw new NullPointerException("Will fail");
}

@Test
public void fail2() throw IOException {
    throw new IOException("Will fail");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JUnit 4, you can explicitly assert that a @Test should fail with a given exception using the `expected` property of the `@Test` annotation:

```
  @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
  public void expectNPE {
     String s = null;
     s.toString();
  }
```

See [JUnit4 documentation on it](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html).

Comment: Wrong, according to doc "cause a test method to succeed if and only if an exception of the specified class is thrown", so you say the opposite ;-)

Comment: Let's leave it for historical reasons, but remove if you get any minus.

Answer (score 0):

Use :
assert or Assert.assertTrue as you like at the end